# Postgres-11 : Alter Table dynamically

Tags: postgresql, dynamic

I am trying to alter table based on another table dynamically.
Below is the piece of code i wrote in postgresql stored procedure.
But running out into some syntax errors.
Please help me here.

I just started working in postgresql and i am from sql server background. Like how we do in sql server print stmts do debug dynamic queries inside procedures; do we have any link to refer please share that as well. It would help me.

```
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS temp_table;
    CREATE TEMP TABLE temp_table AS
    with cte as
    (
        select column_name,data_type,character_maximum_length
        from information_schema."columns" c 
        where table_name = 'customer_new' and table_schema = 'public'
        and column_default is null
    )
    ,cte1 as
    (
        select column_name,data_type,character_maximum_length
        from information_schema."columns" c 
        where table_name = 'customer_old' and table_schema = 'public'
        and column_default is null
    )
    select cte.column_name,
    case when cte.character_maximum_length is not null then cte.data_type||'('||cte.character_maximum_length||')' else cte.data_type end as data_type
    from cte
    left join cte1 on cte.column_name = cte1.column_name
    where cte1.column_name is null;
    
    for v_column_name,v_data_type in SELECT column_name,data_type FROM temp_table
    loop
        execute format ('alter table %s add column  %s  %s  ;', v_dump_table_name, v_column_name, v_data_type);
    end loop;

    DROP TABLE IF EXISTS temp_table;
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: syntax error is in the for loop. What are you trying to do?

Comment: @CarlKristensen..I am trying to add columns in table dynamically.

Answer (score 0):

```
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS temp_table;
    CREATE TEMP TABLE temp_table AS
    with cte as
    (
        select column_name,data_type,character_maximum_length
        from information_schema."columns" c 
        where table_name = 'customer_new' and table_schema = 'public'
        and column_default is null
    )
    ,cte1 as
    (
        select column_name,data_type,character_maximum_length
        from information_schema."columns" c 
        where table_name = 'customer_old' and table_schema = 'public'
        and column_default is null
    )
    select 'alter table '||v_dump_table_name||' add column '||cte2.column_name||' '||data_type 
    as col
    from cte2;

    for v_column in SELECT col FROM temp_table
    loop
        execute format ('%s  ;', v_column);
    end loop;

    DROP TABLE IF EXISTS temp_table;
```